# Unknown provider Error when trying to inject dependency on Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I'm trying to inject "modal" directive in my userMenuController the following way:

```
angular.module('mgApp.controllers').controller('userMenuController', ['$scope', 'modals', function($scope, modals) { ... }])
```

Here's modals.js:

```
angular.module('mgApp.directives').directive('modals', function(){ ... })
```

And on app.js, app is defined like this:

```
var app = angular.module('mgApp',['templates', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'mgApp.filters', 'mgApp.directives', 'mgApp.services', 'mgApp.controllers']);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: modalsProvider <- modals <- userMenuController
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why you don't everything inside the same module mgApp?
I'm mean, your directives and controllers?

Answer (score 1):

a quick thought: make sure you have included all .js files as

```
<script src="*.js"></script>
```

in index.html file

Comment: it happens to me almost every time :)